# Por que essa calculadora em php não está funcionando?

Tags: php, matemática

```
<body>
<form role="form" action="pratica_fazer_calculadora.php" method="get">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="primeiro_numero"/>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Soma</option>
        <option value="2">Subtração</option>
        <option value="3">Divisão</option>
        <option value="1">Multiplicação</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="segundo_numero"/>
    <button type="submit">Ver resultado</button>
</form>    

    <?php 
      $num_1 = $_GET ['primeiro_numero'];
      $num_2 = $_GET ['segundo_numero'];

      $operacao[1] = 1;
      $operacao[2] = 2;
      $operacao[3] = 3;
      $operacao[4] = 4;

      $resultado = null;

      if($operacao[1]){
          $resultado = ($num_1 + $num_2);
      }
      echo $resultado;

    ?>
</body>
```

O interessante é que não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que exatamente não está funcionando? Que erro retorna?

Comment: Ai está o problema. Simplismente não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro. É como se ele pegasse os dados e sumisse com eles.

Comment: A soma está acontecendo, se vc quer que as outras operações funcionem, vc precisa definir condições para elas tb

Comment: Não sei quanto a você. Mas aqui o resultado não é impresso na tela. Na sua ele aparece?

Comment: Aqui funcionou, mas tem algumas coisas estranhas nessa calculadora, não sei se é apenas um teste, mas há muita coisa desnecessária que pode ser simplificada, vou postar um exemplo

Comment: @Bacco eu testei o codigo dele aqui, e a soma(unica operação) funcionou

Comment: "_É como se ele pegasse os dados e sumisse com eles._".. rachei! rs :D

Comment: @Shinchila_Matadora funciona no sentido de que vai somar incondicionalmente, pois o valor do item 1 do array é 1. Na prática "parece que funciona" apenas. Seria como você fazer um `echo 3` e dizer que funciona sempre que você testa com 1 + 2 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não funciona por não ter sido programada para funcionar.

Antes de mais nada, vamos por um nome no `select` e consertar o item 4:

```
<select name="operacao"> <!-- aqui eu pus um "name" -->
    <option value="1">Soma</option>
    <option value="2">Subtração</option>
    <option value="3">Divisão</option>
    <option value="4">Multiplicação</option>
</select>
```

Depois, no PHP:

```
<?php 
  $num_1    = $_GET ['primeiro_numero'];
  $num_2    = $_GET ['segundo_numero'];
  $operacao = $_GET ['operacao'];           // recuperamos a operação

  if ($operacao == 1) {                     // e comparamos para ver qual usar
      $resultado = ($num_1 + $num_2);
  } else if ($operacao == 2) {
      $resultado = ($num_1 - $num_2);
  } else if ($operacao == 3) {

     // ... vai repetindo o elseif e fazendo as operações corretas ...
  }
  echo $resultado;

?>
```

Não troquei o `if` por `switch` por que entendo que está aprendendo, mas recomendo usar no futuro.

Answer (score 2):

Então, fiz algumas alterações no código e finalizei o arquivo.
Coloquei uma validação para o `$_GET` para não dar erro quando você entra na página.
E adicionei um `switch` para realizar as operações, está funcionando normalmente.

```
<body>
<form role="form" action="pratica_fazer_calculadora.php" method="get">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="primeiro_numero"/>
    <select name="operacao">
        <option value="1">Soma</option>
        <option value="2">Subtração</option>
        <option value="3">Divisão</option>
        <option value="4">Multiplicação</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="segundo_numero"/>
    <button type="submit">Ver resultado</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)) {
   $num_1 = (double)isset($_GET ['primeiro_numero']) ? $_GET ['primeiro_numero'] : 0;
   $num_2 = (double)isset($_GET ['segundo_numero']) ? $_GET ['segundo_numero'] : 0;

    $resultado = null;

switch ($_GET['operacao']) {
    case 1:
        $resultado = ($num_1 + $num_2);
        break;
    case 2;
        $resultado = ($num_1 - $num_2);
        break;
    case 3;
        $resultado = ($num_1 / $num_2);
        break;
    case 4;
        $resultado = ($num_1 * $num_2);
        break;
}

    echo 'O Resultado é : ' .$resultado;
}
?>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Fiz de uma forma diferente dos companheiros acima só por desencargo de consciência, e mostrar outras possibilidades também.

Ao invés de definir um `value` direto no `<option>`, definir que a operação aconteça de acordo com o nome que esta dentro dos `<option>` disponíveis:

```
<body>
<form role="form" action="teste2.php" method="get">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="primeiro_numero"/>
    <select name="operacao">
        <option>Soma</option>
        <option>Subtração</option>
        <option>Divisão</option>
        <option>Multiplicação</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Digite um número" name="segundo_numero"/>
    <button type="submit">Ver resultado</button>
</form>    

    <?php 
      $num_1 = $_GET ['primeiro_numero'];
      $num_2 = $_GET ['segundo_numero'];
      $operacao = $_GET['operacao'];

      if($operacao == "Soma"){
          $resultado = ($num_1 + $num_2);
          echo $resultado;

      } else if($operacao == "Subtração"){
          $resultado = ($num_1 - $num_2);
          echo $resultado;

      } else if($operacao == "Divisão"){
          $resultado = ($num_1 / $num_2);
          echo $resultado;

      } else if($operacao == "Multiplicação"){
          $resultado = ($num_1 * $num_2);
          echo $resultado;
      }
    ?>
</body>
```